# Simple linked list program just isn't working

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, nodes, free

I'm just scratching the surface with nodes and linked lists, so I've been trying to create a linked lists that prints out nodes from 1-10. However, it's full of problems. The program gives me a runtime error and segmentation fault, I also have errors when running valgrind.

The comments are more for me, to show that I (hopefully) know what each command is doing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    typedef struct node {
        int value;
        struct node* next;
    }
    node;

    //creates nodes for head, tmp, content
    node* head = NULL;
    node* tmp = NULL;
    node* content = NULL;

    head->next = content; //head node points to content

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        content = malloc(sizeof(node)); //creates new node
        content->value = i; //node data becomes i
        tmp->next = content; //tmp node points to content node
        tmp = tmp->next; //tmp node becomes next content node
        content->next = NULL; //content node points to null
        printf("%i ", content->value); //see node value
    }

    while (head != NULL) {
        node* temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"creates nodes for head, tmp, content"* Nope, creates pointers. You need to allocate memory for each of those using `malloc` before you use them. So for example, `head->next = content` is an instant segfault, because `head` is `NULL`.

Comment: I'll be honest with you, this code is based on pseudocode from a YouTube video. I understand what you're saying, and I think I get what was going on in that video, but what I'm really confused about is the tmp part. So tmp needs to point to content, so the linked list doesn't get orphaned (is that correct)? So that's why tmp->next = content occurs, meaning it points to the content node. What I'm not sure about is the whole tmp = tmp->next command. Is this saying tmp becomes the tmp pointer?

Comment: Imagine you have two nodes: A and B, and the `next` pointer in A points to B. If `tmp` points to A, then `tmp = tmp->next` will change `tmp` so that it points to B. But it doesn't do anything to A or B. Which is to say that in C, there's a difference between an **instance** of a `struct`, and a **pointer** to a `struct`. And if you've confused yourself by watching bad YouTube videos, then you're going to need a good tutor to help you understand that distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so let's break this down

section by section

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    // Data section
    typedef struct node {
        int value;
        struct node* next;
    }
    node;
    node* head = NULL; // a pointer to what will be the head of the list
    node* content; // a utility pointer
    node* temp; // a utility pointer
    int i; // iteration var

    // Code Section
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        if (head == NULL) {
            // The list is empty when this condition triigers
            // we initialize the first node and assign head to point to it
            head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); // allocate memory to the pointer. Also make sure the memory pointed to is of a node type
                                                // This is important because it will allow us use -> operator to assign values to the pointed
                                                // at memory
            head -> value = i; // assign the value i to the value field of the pointed to memory
            head -> next = NULL; // assign the next pointer of the pointed to memory to NULL
        } else {
            // iterate over the list till we reach the end. 
            // Once we do, assign more memory at the end, assign the memory a value and make it's next pointer be NULL
            content = head;
            while (content -> next != NULL) {
                content = content -> next;
            }
            content -> next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            content -> next -> value = i;
        }

    }

    while (head != NULL) {
        temp = head;
        printf("Node data: %d\n", temp -> value);
        head = head->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Data section

```
// Data section
    typedef struct node {
        int value;
        struct node* next;
    }
    node;
    node* head = NULL; // a pointer to what will be the head of the list
    node* content; // a utility pointer
    node* temp; // a utility pointer
    int i; // iteration var
```

When I learnt to program in C if you didn't declare the vars your function used upfront at the top of the function, the compiler would complain. For some reason it works now.

When you declare something as a pointer, you are only declaring it. You cannot assign values to it before you allocate memory to the pointer.

#### Code Section (I don't know what else to call it)

```
// Code Section
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        if (head == NULL) {
            // The list is empty when this condition triigers
            // we initialize the first node and assign head to point to it
            head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); // allocate memory to the pointer. Also make sure the memory pointed to is of a node type
                                                // This is important because it will allow us use -> operator to assign values to the pointed
                                                // at memory
            head -> value = i; // assign the value i to the value field of the pointed to memory
            head -> next = NULL; // assign the next pointer of the pointed to memory to NULL
        } else {
            // iterate over the list till we reach the end. 
            // Once we do, assign more memory at the end, assign the memory a value and make it's next pointer be NULL
            content = head;
            while (content -> next != NULL) {
                content = content -> next;
            }
            content -> next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            content -> next -> value = i;
        }

    }
```

The right way to allocate memory and make sure the allocate memory is of a specific type is using `malloc` and cast it to the appropriate type. As you can see in some lines like `content -> next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));`. Ensuring the type of the memory allocated is done with the typecast `(node*)`

What you were doing wrong

1. `head->next = content;` is wrong. `head` at the time of this statement in your code is `NULL`. It doesn't have a `next` pointer that you can point to anything.
2. `tmp->next = content;` same as above
3. `content = malloc(sizeof(node));` works best with the *typecast* I outlined above
4. As others have pointed out, `malloc` can fail for a variety of reasons. It returns a `NULL` which you should check for.
5. You never actually make `head` the head of your list

Comment: So when I did node* head = NULL or node* (whatever) = NULL, without malloc(sizeof(node)), I didn't really create a node...is that correct? Some other program I copied, when I used **(node*)malloc(sizeof(node))** instead of **malloc(sizeof(node))**, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: No. You did not create a node. You *declared* a pointer that is meant to point to chunks of memory whose spatial arrangement if that of a node, but right now point to *NULL*. If you got a compile time error when you typecast the `malloc` call, your error was probably elsewhere. without knowing what program you copied it is difficult to say. I compiled this program and can confirm it works.

Comment: One thing I'm confused about is the **content = head**, **content = content->next**, or any other similar statements, since these are all pointers. Since these are pointers, they're not being assigned values, so does that mean they're now pointing to something else instead (besides NULL)?

Comment: Yes, they now point to whatever they're being assigned to. If the stuff on the left hand side of the `=` is a `malloc` then right hand side points to a new chunk of memory. If the left hand side is another pointer, then it points to whatever that pointer points to

Comment: This is unrelated to my question, but has to do with pointers in general. I know that in some cases the **&** is used with pointers. In what situations should that be used?

Comment: It's the [Address of](https://www.hermetic.ch/cfunlib/ast_amp2.htm) operator. The link has a lot more detail than I can go into in a comment

Comment: So I copied your code verbatim, and it works, now I need to figure out how to do this my own way. Another question I have is this statement **content -> next -> value = i;**, I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169797/discussion-between-srini-and-00saad).

Answer (score 0):

The line `head->next = content; //head node points to content` doesn't make any sense. `head` doesn't point to anything (you assigned it null) and neither does content, so saying `head->next = content` is meaningless at this point. You need to assign memory to the head node before you start your loop or add a condition in the loop saying something like `if(head == NULL) head = content` after you assign memory to content. And check to make sure that your memory allocation succeeds.

Comment: How can I check if memory allocation succeeds?

Comment: Check if the result of malloc returns a null pointer. `if((content = malloc(sizeof(node))) == NULL) { // Handle error here }`